# Editing data entry in RecyclerView after ordering the entries ends up editing different entry after changing screens Android Studio

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm a beginner and Android Studio and I'm attempting to create a student tracker application which communicates with Firebase Realtime Database and Firebase Cloud Storage. The purpose is to keep track of student entries, allow me to edit entries, and sort entries.

After sorting (alphabetically) the Student items (stored in an ArrayList), it repopulates the RecyclerView with the sorted entries, which is working great. But if I edit an entry after sorting the view and save the edit, the view is no longer ordered alphabetically and it ends up editing a different entry. I'd appreciate any assistance possible in resolving this issue.

Here are some images of what it looks like:

[View Students Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fls26.png)

[View Profile Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lvoCc.png)

Here is all the necessary code for this process:

**ViewStudents.java**

```
package com.example.studenttracker;

    import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager;
    import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
    import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
    
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.content.SharedPreferences;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.os.Message;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.ImageButton;
    
    import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
    import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
    import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
    import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
    import com.google.firebase.database.Query;
    import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
    
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Collections;
    import java.util.Comparator;
    
    public class ViewStudents extends AppCompatActivity {


    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    Button addStudent;


    private DatabaseReference myRef;

    public ArrayList<Students> students;
    public ArrayList<Students> unorderedStudents;
    private RecyclerAdapter recyclerAdapter;
    ImageButton homeButton;
    private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    private EditText mEditTextAge;
    private EditText mEditTextAssignment;
    public static Students student;
    private Button order;
    private final String checkIfOrderedClick = "orderedCheck";
    private int orderCounter;
    public static int realPos;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_students);

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        homeButton=findViewById(R.id.homeButton);
        addStudent = findViewById(R.id.addStudentButton);
        sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(checkIfOrderedClick,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        mEditTextAge = findViewById(R.id.EditTextAge);
        order = findViewById(R.id.orderStudents);
        mEditTextAssignment = findViewById(R.id.EditTextAssignment);

        order.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                orderStudents();
            }
        });
        homeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(ViewStudents.this, MainMenu.class));
            }
        });
        addStudent.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(ViewStudents.this, AddStudent.class));
            }
        });

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, 2));
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);


        myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

        students = new ArrayList<>();
        unorderedStudents = new ArrayList<>();

        ClearAll();

        GetDataFromFirebase();

//        LoadInt();
        if (orderCounter ==1) {
            orderStudents();
        }


    }
    private void GetDataFromFirebase() {
        Query query = myRef.child("student");

        query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                ClearAll();
                for(DataSnapshot snapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Students student = new Students();
                    if (snapshot.child("url").getValue() == null) {
                        student.setImageUrl(snapshot.child("imageUrl").getValue().toString());
                    }
                    else {
                        student.setImageUrl(snapshot.child("url").getValue().toString());

                    }

                    student.setName(snapshot.child("name").getValue().toString());
                    if (snapshot.child("age").getValue().toString()!=null ) {
                        student.setAge(snapshot.child("age").getValue().toString());
                    }
                    if (snapshot.child("Daily Grade").getValue().toString()!=null) {
                        student.setGrade(snapshot.child("Daily Grade").getValue().toString());
                    }
                    if (snapshot.child("assignment").getValue().toString()!=null) {
                        student.setAssignment(snapshot.child("assignment").getValue().toString());
                    }


                    students.add(student);
                    unorderedStudents.add(student);
                }
                recyclerAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter(getApplicationContext(), students);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerAdapter);
                recyclerAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(new RecyclerAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(int position) {
                        student = students.get(position);
                        realPos = position;
                        Intent viewProf = new Intent(ViewStudents.this, ViewProfile.class);
                        startActivity(viewProf);
                    }
                });
                recyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
    private void ClearAll() {
        if (unorderedStudents != null) {
            unorderedStudents.clear();
        }
        unorderedStudents = new ArrayList<>();
        if (students != null) {
            students.clear();

            if(recyclerAdapter != null) {
                recyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
        students = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    public void orderStudents() {
        orderCounter = 1;
        SaveInt();
        Collections.sort( students, new Comparator<Students>() {
            @Override
            public int compare( Students o1, Students o2 ) {
                return o1.name.compareTo( o2.name );
            }
        });
        recyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
    private void SaveInt() {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putInt(checkIfOrderedClick, orderCounter);
        editor.clear().commit();
    }
    private void LoadInt() {
        orderCounter = sharedPreferences.getInt(checkIfOrderedClick, 0);
    }
}
```

**ViewProfile.java**

```
package com.example.studenttracker;
    
    import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager;
    import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
    import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
    
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.content.SharedPreferences;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.os.Message;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.ImageButton;
    
    import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
    import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
    import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
    import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
    import com.google.firebase.database.Query;
    import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
    
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Collections;
    import java.util.Comparator;
    
    public class ViewStudents extends AppCompatActivity {
    
    
        RecyclerView recyclerView;
        Button addStudent;
    
    
        private DatabaseReference myRef;
    
        public ArrayList<Students> students;
        public ArrayList<Students> unorderedStudents;
        private RecyclerAdapter recyclerAdapter;
        ImageButton homeButton;
        private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
        private EditText mEditTextAge;
        private EditText mEditTextAssignment;
        public static Students student;
        private Button order;
        private final String checkIfOrderedClick = "orderedCheck";
        private int orderCounter;
        public static int realPos;
    
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_students);
    
            recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
            homeButton=findViewById(R.id.homeButton);
            addStudent = findViewById(R.id.addStudentButton);
            sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(checkIfOrderedClick,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            mEditTextAge = findViewById(R.id.EditTextAge);
            order = findViewById(R.id.orderStudents);
            mEditTextAssignment = findViewById(R.id.EditTextAssignment);
    
            order.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    orderStudents();
                }
            });
            homeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(ViewStudents.this, MainMenu.class));
                }
            });
            addStudent.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(ViewStudents.this, AddStudent.class));
                }
            });
    
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, 2));
            recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    
    
            myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    
            students = new ArrayList<>();
            unorderedStudents = new ArrayList<>();
    
            ClearAll();
    
            GetDataFromFirebase();
    
    //        LoadInt();
            if (orderCounter ==1) {
                orderStudents();
            }
    
    
        }
        private void GetDataFromFirebase() {
            Query query = myRef.child("student");
    
            query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    ClearAll();
                    for(DataSnapshot snapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        Students student = new Students();
                        if (snapshot.child("url").getValue() == null) {
                            student.setImageUrl(snapshot.child("imageUrl").getValue().toString());
                        }
                        else {
                            student.setImageUrl(snapshot.child("url").getValue().toString());
    
                        }
    //                    student.setAge(mEditTextAge.getText().toString());
    //                    student.setAssignment(mEditTextAssignment.getText().toString().trim());
                        student.setName(snapshot.child("name").getValue().toString());
                        if (snapshot.child("age").getValue().toString()!=null ) {
                            student.setAge(snapshot.child("age").getValue().toString());
                        }
                        if (snapshot.child("Daily Grade").getValue().toString()!=null) {
                            student.setGrade(snapshot.child("Daily Grade").getValue().toString());
                        }
                        if (snapshot.child("assignment").getValue().toString()!=null) {
                            student.setAssignment(snapshot.child("assignment").getValue().toString());
                        }
    
    
                        students.add(student);
                        unorderedStudents.add(student);
                    }
                    recyclerAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter(getApplicationContext(), students);
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerAdapter);
                    recyclerAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(new RecyclerAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onItemClick(int position) {
                            student = students.get(position);
                            realPos = position;
                            Intent viewProf = new Intent(ViewStudents.this, ViewProfile.class);
                            startActivity(viewProf);
                        }
                    });
                    recyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    
                }
    
                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
    
                }
            });
        }
        private void ClearAll() {
            if (unorderedStudents != null) {
                unorderedStudents.clear();
            }
            unorderedStudents = new ArrayList<>();
            if (students != null) {
                students.clear();
    
                if(recyclerAdapter != null) {
                    recyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
            students = new ArrayList<>();
        }
        public void orderStudents() {
            orderCounter = 1;
            SaveInt();
            Collections.sort( students, new Comparator<Students>() {
                @Override
                public int compare( Students o1, Students o2 ) {
                    return o1.name.compareTo( o2.name );
                }
            });
            recyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    
        }
        private void SaveInt() {
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
            editor.putInt(checkIfOrderedClick, orderCounter);
            editor.clear().commit();
        }
        private void LoadInt() {
            orderCounter = sharedPreferences.getInt(checkIfOrderedClick, 0);
        }
    }
```

**RecyclerAdapter.java**

```
package com.example.studenttracker;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private OnItemClickListener mListener;
    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(int position);
    }
    public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener) {
        mListener = listener;
    }
    private static final String Tag = "RecyclerView";
    private Context mContext;
    private ArrayList<Students> studentsArrayList;

    public RecyclerAdapter(Context mContext, ArrayList<Students> studentsArrayList) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.studentsArrayList = studentsArrayList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.student_item,parent,false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        //TextView
        holder.textView.setText(studentsArrayList.get(position).getName());

        Glide.with(mContext).load(studentsArrayList.get(position).getImageUrl()).into(holder.imageView);




    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return studentsArrayList.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        ImageView imageView;
        TextView textView;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            textView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (mListener != null) {
                        int position = getAdapterPosition();
                        if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                            mListener.onItemClick(position);
                        }

                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

**activity_view_students.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ViewStudents">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/addStudentButton" >

    </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/addStudentButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Add Students"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/orderStudents"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Order Students"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/homeButton"
        android:layout_width="42dp"
        android:layout_height="38dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/addStudentButton"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/orderStudents"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_home_icon_foreground" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**activity_view_profile.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ViewProfile">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editAssignment"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/textView4"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView4" />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editDailyGrade"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/textView5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView5" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/profile_Image"
        android:layout_width="235dp"
        android:layout_height="231dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:text="Name: "
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/profile_Image" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:text="Age:"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:text="Assignment:"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView3" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:text="Daily Grade:"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView4" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editName"
        android:layout_width="202dp"
        android:layout_height="42dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/textView2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView2" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editAge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/textView3"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView3" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/saveButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="18dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="27dp"
        android:text="Save"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/editButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="17dp"
        android:text="Edit"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/cancelButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="17dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="27dp"
        android:text="Cancel"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**activity_student_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context=".DailyGrading">


    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        app:cardElevation="2dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="5dp"

        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:paddingTop="20dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:textSize="16sp" />



    </RelativeLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many changes we need to make in both of Activity Classes, few of them are-

1. No need to setup the recycle adapter in GetDataFromFirebase()
   method.
2. Change the recycle view listener, to pass StudentID
3. Passing the StudentID to ViewProfile Activity will be a good option
   and let ViewProfile activity find the student values an you can
   update the value using the same ID.
4. For Sorting, just have a method to update existing
   ArrayList rather then maintaining two different list.
5. There is no need for any recycle view in ViewProfile Activity

Modify code could be as follows -

**RecycleAdapter**

```
public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private static final String Tag = "RecyclerView";
    private Context mContext;
    private ArrayList<Students> studentsArrayList;
    private OnItemClickListener mListener;

    public RecyclerAdapter(Context mContext) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
    }

    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(Student student, int position);
    }

    public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener) {
        mListener = listener;
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.student_item, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        //TextView
        holder.textView.setText(studentsArrayList.get(position).getName());
        Glide.with(mContext).load(studentsArrayList.get(position).getImageUrl()).into(holder.imageView);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if (studentsArrayList == null)
            return 0;
        else
            return studentsArrayList.size();
    }

    public void setStudentArrayList(ArrayList<Students> studentsArrayList) {
        this.studentsArrayList = studentsArrayList;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        ImageView imageView;
        TextView textView;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            textView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (mListener != null) {
                        int position = getAdapterPosition();
                        if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                            mListener.onItemClick(student,position);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

**ViewStudent.java**

```
public class ViewStudents extends AppCompatActivity{

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private Button addStudent;
    private DatabaseReference myRef;
    public ArrayList<Students> students;
    private RecyclerAdapter recyclerAdapter;
    ImageButton homeButton;
    private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    private EditText mEditTextAge;
    private EditText mEditTextAssignment;
    private Button order;
    private final String checkIfOrderedClick = "orderedCheck";
    // User boolean value to check if the list is order or not
    private boolean isOrder;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_students);
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        homeButton = findViewById(R.id.homeButton);
        addStudent = findViewById(R.id.addStudentButton);
        mEditTextAge = findViewById(R.id.EditTextAge);
        order = findViewById(R.id.orderStudents);
        mEditTextAssignment = findViewById(R.id.EditTextAssignment);

        myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

        order.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (!isOrder)
                    orderStudents();
                else
                    Toast.makeText(ViewStudents.this, "Oder Already", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        homeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(ViewStudents.this, MainMenu.class));
            }
        });
        addStudent.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(ViewStudents.this, AddStudent.class));
            }
        });

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, 2));
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter(getApplicationContext());

        //student array is null but we can pass it because there is already a check on getItemCount method
        recyclerAdapter.setStudentArrayList(students);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerAdapter);

        GetDataFromFirebase();

        recyclerAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(new RecyclerAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(Student student, int position) {
                //Take selected student ID and pass the ID to ViewProfile Activity
                //TODO you can remove position from parameter as well
                String studentID = student.getID();
                Intent viewProf = new Intent(ViewStudents.this, ViewProfile.class);
                viewProf.putExtra("STUDENT_ID", studentID);
                startActivity(viewProf);
            }
        });
    }

    private void GetDataFromFirebase() {
        //initialize student array list
        students = new ArrayList<>();
        Query query = myRef.child("student");
        query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                ClearAll();
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Students student = new Students();
                    if (snapshot.child("url").getValue() == null) {
                        student.setImageUrl(snapshot.child("imageUrl").getValue().toString());
                    } else {
                        student.setImageUrl(snapshot.child("url").getValue().toString());
                    }
                    student.setName(snapshot.child("name").getValue().toString());
                    if (snapshot.child("age").getValue().toString() != null) {
                        student.setAge(snapshot.child("age").getValue().toString());
                    }
                    if (snapshot.child("Daily Grade").getValue().toString() != null) {
                        student.setGrade(snapshot.child("Daily Grade").getValue().toString());
                    }
                    if (snapshot.child("assignment").getValue().toString() != null) {
                        student.setAssignment(snapshot.child("assignment").getValue().toString());
                    }
                    students.add(student);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        });
        //now student array has the students so we can update the student list
        recyclerAdapter.setStudentArrayList(students);
    }

    public void orderStudents() {
        isOrder = true;
        Collections.sort(students, new Comparator<Students>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Students o1, Students o2) {
                return o1.name.compareTo(o2.name);
            }
        });
        //now student is sorted so we can again update student list
        recyclerAdapter.setStudentArrayList(students);

    }
}
```

**ViewProfile.java**

```
public class ViewProfile extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button addStudent;
    private DatabaseReference myRef;
    ImageButton homeButton;
    private EditText mEditTextAge;
    private EditText mEditTextAssignment;
    public static Students student;
    private final String checkIfOrderedClick = "orderedCheck";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_students);

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        homeButton = findViewById(R.id.homeButton);
        addStudent = findViewById(R.id.addStudentButton);
        mEditTextAge = findViewById(R.id.EditTextAge);
        mEditTextAssignment = findViewById(R.id.EditTextAssignment);

        addStudent.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(ViewStudents.this, AddStudent.class));
                finish();
            }
        });

        myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

        if(getIntent()!=null){
            String studentID = getIntent().getStringExtra("STUDENT_ID");
            getStudentFromID(studentID);
        }
    }

    private void getStudentFromID(String studentID) {
        Query query = myRef.child("student");

        CollectionReference collectionReference = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
                .collection("Student");

        Query query = collectionReference.whereEqualTo("studentID", studentID);
        query.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    if (task.getResult().isEmpty()) {
                        // if you end up here then studentID is not matching with any saved student value
                        // try to check the studentID
                    } else {
                        //found matching student simply setup values
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.e(TAG, "onComplete: " + task.getException());
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Another way could be to transfer values of selected student and use them to update student fields. For that we need to update the recycle view click listener as

```
public interface OnItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(Student student, String name, int age, String assignment, String grade);
    }
```

and the onClickListener on ViewStudent Activity will be as-

```
recyclerAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(new RecyclerAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(Student student, String name, int age, String assignment, String grade) {
                //Take selected student ID and pass the ID to ViewProfile Activity
                String studentID = student.getID();
                Intent viewProf = new Intent(ViewStudents.this, ViewProfile.class);
                viewProf.putExtra("STUDENT_ID", studentID);
                viewProf.putExtra("STUDENT_NAME", name);
                viewProf.putExtra("STUDENT_AGE", age);
                viewProf.putExtra("STUDENT_ASSIGNMENT", assignment);
                viewProf.putExtra("STUDENT_GRADE", grade);
                startActivity(viewProf);
            }
        });
```

In that way there is no need to query firebase for selected student's values, but again you will need studentID to save changes to student's values.

There could be many things which need to take care as well like removing unnecessary variables and optimizing code but I guess you will be able to achieve it as you go down the way. :)

Happy Coding !!

**Edit (cause of different item getting edited)**

Real reason why you are getting editing in different entry because you were using position to get document from firebase not StudentID. Firebase is no-SQLite database means it will not maintain any table structure like you get with SQL Database. That's why you can never be certain about which document will be at position 1. Again solution is using StudentID.

Comment: Thank you. I also utilized something similar to your suggestion of the studentid and it worked out. The optimization is something I will surely take a look at. Cheers.